# I get pandas_datareader.data.DataReader() error after installing the yfinance package

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader, yfinance

My anaconda spyder `pandas_datareader.data.DataReader()` doesn't work after installing `yfinance` package. Actually `yfinance` asks me to install the `multitasking` package, and this seems to be the cause of the error, when a call `DataReader()`.

```
File "/Users/Daniel/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 95, in download_time.sleep(0.01)
```

I could see some similar claims on the internet, but without a solution.

The simplified code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
import datetime

def dataQuery(pSeriesName, pSeriesSource, pInitDate):
    df = web.DataReader(pSeriesName, pSeriesSource, pInitDate)
    return df 

initDate2 = returnLastYMD(initDate)  

cpiMomSlice = dataQuery('CPIAUCSL', 'fred', initDate2).pct_change()
```

And spyder console error log:

[image: Console msg]

Comment: Have you updated `pandas_datareader`? It should be `'0.9.0'` and `yfinance` version `'0.1.55'`. If the issue is with version `0.1.55` roll back to version`0.1.54`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Tried `yfinance` `0.1.54`. Same error.

Comment: Please include the specific code you're using, which results in the error, and include the entire TraceBack. Both as text, not screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add updates in comments.

Comment: If I run this same code, without installing the yfinance package, it works fine.